# How can I get the value of labels associated with checkboxes (and did I break jsfiddle)?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jsfiddle

I need to build a csv of dept numbers the user selects.

I started off with this HTML:

```
<button id="btnDept">select Depts</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Select the Depts you want to include in the report" style="display:none;">
    <div>
        <label for="ckbx2">2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ckbx2" />
        <label for="ckbx3" id="lbl3">3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ckbx3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

...and this jQuery:

```
var deptsSelected = '';
$("#btnDept").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true
    });
    $('checkbox').click(function() {
        deptsSelected += this.val + ',';
        alert(deptsSelected);
    });
});
```

...that does nothing about showing depts selected -- and that makes sense, as "this" is presumably the checkbox, and certainly not the label. I am going to have dozens of checkboxes in this dialog,  and don't want to have to write something like this:

$('#ckbx3').click(function() {
    deptsSelected += $('lbl3').val + ',';
    alert(deptsSelected);
});

...for each and every checkbox/label pair (even with this brute force approach, though, the code above showed this alert, not what I was expecting/hoping for:

[image]

Heavens to Murgatroid/what the kerfluffle?!?

The jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/aWpPN/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this:

```
var deptsSelected = '';
$("#btnDept").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true
    });
    $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
        deptsSelected += $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text() + ',';
        alert(deptsSelected);
    });
});
```

And here is the fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/yFB6W/

Comment: @ClayShannon, Great!  Glad to be of help.  I suggest you ask a new question for the expansion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705118/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-create-a-csv-of-all-checked-checkboxes-associated-text

Comment: @ClayShannon, please see my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705118/how-can-i-use-jquery-to-create-a-csv-of-all-checked-checkboxes-associated-text

Answer (score 2):

There are other methods, but this one will update an array with the splitted Number value out of your checked checkboxes ID

http://jsfiddle.net/aWpPN/1/

```
$("#btnDept").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true
    });
});

function getChecked() {         
   var deptsSelected = [];
   $('#dialog :checked').each(function() {
        deptsSelected.push( this.id.split('ckbx')[1] );
   });
   alert( deptsSelected );
}

$('#dialog').find('input').change( getChecked );
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `this.val()` with `$('label[for="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').html()`. `$('checkbox')` should be `$('input[type="checkbox"])`

Answer (score 1):

You can add value to your checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="ckbx2" value="2" />
```

Comment: But it does't display, without the "label for."

Comment: No it doesn't display. You use label to put a label on an input/present some information to user about the input and put the value you want to use in the program if user checks the input. You can easily get the value and your label can have any information like "Mark this box if you want to choose number TWO".

Answer (score 1):

This in the answer you want:

```
<input type='button' id='btnDept' value='Depts' />
<div id='dialog' title='Select the Depts you want to include in the report'>
  <div>
    <label for='ckbx2'>2</label>
    <input type='checkbox' id='ckbx2' value='2' />
    <label for='ckbx3' id='lbl3'>3</label>
    <input type='checkbox' id='ckbx3' value='3' />
  </div>
</div>
var deptsSelected = [];
$("#btnDept").click(function(){
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    modal: true
  });
});
$(':checkbox').click(function(){
  $(':checkbox').each(function(i){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      deptsSelected[i] = $(this).val();
    }
    else{
      deptsSelected.splice(i, 1);
    }
  });
  alert(deptsSelected.join());
});
```

I put a new fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/PHPglue/akp7Q/1/ . You forgot values for your `checkbox`es and your jQuery needed help as well.

Answer (score 1):

**By adding value to the checkboxes same as you have in label.**

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="checkBoxContainer">
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" value="value1" checked="">
        <label for="checkbox1"> value1 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" value="value2" checked="">
        <label for="checkbox2"> value2 </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And than iterate over container getting those values. *(example only checked)*

```
var checkboxArray =[];

$('#checkBoxContainer :checked').each(function() { checkboxArray.push($(this).val()); });
```