# How can I use jQuery to create a csv of all checked checkboxes associated text?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I got most of the way to what I need with an answer to my question here: [How can I get the value of labels associated with checkboxes (and did I break jsfiddle)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17688489/how-can-i-get-the-value-of-labels-associated-with-checkboxes-and-did-i-break-js)

...but I have another related question, namely, "*How can I use jQuery to create a csv of all checked checkboxes associated text?*"

What I've got so far, with the missing piece commented, is here: [JS fiddler link](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/yFB6W/1/)

The HTML is:

```
<button id="btnDept">select Depts</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Select the Depts you want to include in the report" style="display:none;">
    <div>
        <section class="breakAfter">
            <label for="ckbxSelectAll">Select All</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ckbxSelectAll" />
            <label for="ckbxDeselectAll">Deselect All</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="ckbxDeselectAll" />
        </section>
        <label for="ckbx2">2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ckbx2" />
        <label for="ckbx3" id="lbl3">3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ckbx3" />
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
.breakAfter {
    display:block;
}
```

The jQuery is:

```
var deptsSelected = '';
$("#btnDept").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true
    });
    $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
        var checkedVal = $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text();

        if (checkedVal == "Select All") {
            $(":checkbox").prop("checked", true);
            $("#ckbxDeselectAll").prop("checked", false);
            // How can I add all of the vals to deptsSelected (except "Select All" and "Deselect All")? 
        } else if (checkedVal == "Deselect All") {
            $(":checkbox").prop("checked", false);
            $("#ckbxDeselectAll").prop("checked", true);
            deptsSelected = '';
        } else {
            if (deptsSelected.indexOf(checkedVal) < 0) {
                deptsSelected += $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text() + ',';
            }
        }
        alert(deptsSelected);
    });
});
```

IOW, I need to loop through, I would think, all label elements, appending their text value and a comma (and then lop the final comma off the end).

### UPDATE

I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/yFB6W/1/) to include all the checkboxes I will need:

I created the rest of the checkboxes in a C# utility:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = string.Empty;
    for (int i = 4; i < 100; i++)
    {
        s += string.Format("<label for=\"ckbx{0}\">{0}</label><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"ckbx{0}\" />", i);           
    }
    textBox1.AppendText(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `join` function to generate the `csv` from the `map` of checked checkboxes excluding the 'Select All' `checkbox`.

Following is what you can do:

```
deptsSelected = $.map($(':checkbox:not(#' + this.id + '):checked'), function(elem, index) {
    return $("label[for='" + elem.id + "']").text();
}).join(',');
```

And here is the fiddle that shows this: http://jsfiddle.net/BaKYh/

Here are the documentation for the two new functions I've used:

`map()`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

`join()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: @ClayShannon, Nice!  Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through all of the checkboxes, see which ones are checked, get the value, then add it to 'deptsSelected'. You also need to check to make sure the current checkbox is not 'chkbxSelectAll'.  You will need to do this both when selecting all or selecting single.

```
      $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
            if (this.checked && this.id != "ckbxSelectAll") {
                 deptsSelected +=   $("label[for='" + this.id + "']").text() + ',';
            }
        });
```

Rough Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yFB6W/6/

Answer (score 1):

Here is fully working [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/yFB6W/11/) hopefully demonstrating what you're after.

Here are some handy functions to find what the state of the checkboxes are in.

```
var checkedResults = $(".value.option").map(function (i, e) {
    return $(e).prop("checked");
}).get();
var areAllChecked = checkedResults.reduce(function (seed, value) {
    return seed && value;
}, true);
var areSomeChecked = checkedResults.reduce(function (seed, value) {
    return seed || value;
}, false);
```

To actually print the values of the checkboxes I added data attributes (**data-value**) to the checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="value option" data-value="2" id="ckbx2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="value option" data-value="3" id="ckbx3" />
```

Which I can then access like this.

```
// Get an array with all the selected values
var result = $(".value.option:checked").map(function (i, e) {
  return $(e).attr("data-value");
}).get();

// Print the values
console.log("Change", result);

// Or stringify the array and add it to the page
$("#result").text(JSON.stringify(result));
```

In the JSFiddle example I changed the detection and update part of your code.

```
$("#btnDept").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true
    });

    function reportChange() {
        var result = $(".value.option:checked").map(function (i, e) {
            return $(e).attr("data-value");
        }).get();
        console.log("Change", result);
        $("#result").text(JSON.stringify(result));
    }

    $("#ckbxSelectAll").click(function () {
        var isChecked = $("#ckbxSelectAll").prop("checked");
        if (isChecked) {
            $(".value.option").prop("checked", isChecked);
            $("#ckbxDeselectAll").prop("checked", false);
        }
        reportChange();
    });
    $("#ckbxDeselectAll").click(function () {
        $(".value.option, #ckbxSelectAll").removeAttr("checked");
        reportChange();
    });
    $(".value.option").click(function () {
        var checkedResults = $(".value.option").map(function (i, e) {
            return $(e).prop("checked");
        }).get();
        var areAllChecked = checkedResults.reduce(function (seed, value) {
            return seed && value;
        }, true);
        var areSomeChecked = checkedResults.reduce(function (seed, value) {
            return seed || value;
        }, false);
        $("#ckbxDeselectAll").prop("checked", !areSomeChecked);
        $("#ckbxSelectAll").prop("checked", areAllChecked);
        reportChange();
    });
});
```